# Blender 2.93. Help with Rigging Character: Bone Heat Weighing Error

Tags: rigging, bones, error

I am very new to blender and after looking up any tutorials, I tried hand rigging a model I made for a simple animation. When I do, I get an Error. "Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones.  Things I have tried.

I have changed parent locations and added more parent bones.
Parenting bones but they seem to only parent 2 joint offshoots so I have to use the 'keep offset' option
I have tried to use the other options besides bone heat weighing.

Unfortunately. I am not all that advanced at blender and After many tutorials they seem not to give me an answer after following them to a tee.

[image: Failed rigging of ChisaiKuso.Blend to Bones, including error message]

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Sure. here is the file. It might be the problem with the modeling, honestly, I am very new and not that good at all. 

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=JM5rrbz6" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/JM5rrbz6/)

Comment: deleted my original comment because I'd written "merge at center" instead of "by distance".  oops.  When I merged properly you had 46 duplicate vertices. Even so the parenting is failing.  I'll look at it some more.

Comment: No problem. I figured you didn't mean at Center! I know I am asking alot, but why do the duplicated verts cause issues?

Also. I tried, but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: You're not asking a lot.  The algorithm that figures out automatic weights needs an airtight mesh (technically 'manifold mesh') and multiple vertices at the same place amount to 'leaks', so the algorithm breaks.  Turns out I had to turn up the settings on Merge at Center slightly.  I'll post an answer.